# Delete AzureML model using python SDK v2

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

I'm trying to delete an AzureML model using the python SDK v2,
but I couldn't find such functionality.
its a bit surprising, cause there's such functionality in the web UI.

Was looking at both `azure.ai.ml.entities.Model` and `azure.ai.ml.operations.ModelOperations` (the class under which all `ml_client.models.<operation>` operations are defined) - cant find support for delete operation under them.

**Edit 1:**
The v2 CLI doesn't support deletion as well (archiving is not deletion)
[image]

**Edit 2:**
As partial solution, this can be achieved using SDK v1:

```py
from azureml.core import Workspace, Model
workspace = ...
model = Model(workspace=workspace, name=name, version=version)
model.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

> using [Azure  cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ml/model?view=azure-cli-latest) and  python sdk I Deleted Azure ML model using python SDK 1.49.0

- Using Azure cli I got the same command

[image]

- Adding az extension i was able to find delete command

```
  az extension add -n azure-cli-ml
```

[image]

- using az model [delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMYgC.png) I was to delete [model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOZut.png)

```
   az ml model delete --model-id <model_id> --workspace-name <workspace_name> --resource-group <resource_group> --subscription <subscription_id>
```

[image]

- using  python sdk

```py
from azureml.core import Workspace, Model

# Replace with your AzureML workspace details
subscription_id = "your-subscription-id"
resource_group = "your-resource-group"
workspace_name = "your-workspace-name"

# Replace with your model name and version
model_name = "your-model-name"
model_version = 2

workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)

# Get the model using the Model class
model = Model(workspace=workspace, name=model_name, version=model_version)

model = Model(workspace, name=model_name)

model_id = model.id

  

print("Model ID:", model_id)

# Delete the model
model.delete()

print("Model deleted successfully.")
```

[image]

[image]